# How to limit the no. of times cycle should run in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
from itertools import count,repeat,cycle
for i in cycle("raghav"):
    print(i)
    if len(i) >= 6:
       break
```

My code is running infinitely even though i have limit the len, I have also tried `count(i) >= 6` but then it returns an error:

> TypeError: a number is required

Comment: I don't think you actually want to use `cycle` here anyway? `for i in "raghav"` would achieve what you're trying to make `cycle` do.

Comment: @roganjosh Depends. The stop index can be extended and the vanilla approach will not work

Comment: @roganjosh  they could be looking for `raghavr`

Comment: @MosesKoledoye absolutely, but the misunderstanding with `len(i)` when `i` is being printed as single letters made me more inclined to think there was a misunderstanding with `for` loops in general.

Comment: So what would be the *expected* output? Are you trying to limit this to printing 6 individual characters, or to printing the letters from `raghav` 6 times?

Comment: It would be nice if OP can post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @EliSadoff. What do you find unsatisfactory about OP's currently posted code? I agree that the description of the requirement is imprecise but I don't think that the MCVE or its description are an issue.

Comment: printing raghav 6 times @MartijnPieters

Comment: @Dr._Duck: the whole word, or the letters of the word, repeated 6 times. Again, please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @MadPhysicist: it is entirely not clear what the expected output is. The OP has stated in a comment they are trying to print `raghav` 6 times. Or the letters of `raghav` 6 times repeated. It isn't clear, and those explanations certainly differ from what the interpretations the answerers below have made. A proper MCVE includes the expected output, clearly defined.

Comment: I understood. i just have to use repeat instead of cycle. @MartijnPieters

Comment: @Dr._Duck: without an MCVE this question isn't useful to future visitors however. Even the accepted answer has 3 different interpretations of what is wanted, how is anyone supposed to recognise that they have the same issue?

Comment: Sorry, but i am new to stackoverflow , will make sure not to "repeat" ;) this next time. If you know what i mean. @MartijnPieters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for i, x in enumerate(cycle('raghav')):
    print(x)
    if i >= 6:
        break
```

This is a perfect use case for enumerate

Oh, you want to repeatedly print `'raghav'`.  For that use `repeat` not `cycle`:

```
from itertools import repeat
for i, x in enumerate(repeat('raghav')):
    print(x)
    if i == 5:
        break
```

Or just

```
for i in range(5):
    print('raghav')
```

Comment: so here enumerate is actually working on index if i am not wrong

Comment: @Dr._Duck Try for yourself! replace `print(x)` with `print(i, x)` and `if i >= 6:` with something larger, like `if i > 20:`

Comment: @Dr._Duck i misunderstood your question.  please see my edits

Comment: Thanks @Patrick Haugh for your solution

Comment: `repeat()` has a repeat keyword: `for char in repeat('raghav', 6)` will repeat iteration over the letters of the string 6 times.

Answer (score 4):

Set up a `count` object outside the loop and use its `next` method:

```
from itertools import count, cycle

c = count()
for i in cycle("raghav"):
    print(i)
    if next(c) >= 6:
       break
```

Comment: `enumerate` does the counter for you.

Comment: @MadPhysicist They already gave an hint at `count` and had it imported

Comment: OP does not strike me as someone that is intimate with the intricacies of Python iteration.

Comment: From the comments it is clear this isn't what the OP was trying to achieve. I've closed the post until a proper MCVE is provided.

Answer (score 2):

`len(i)` will always be `1` as `i` is just one character in `'raghav'`. If you just want it to print out `'raghav'` letter-by-letter, as it seems, you can do this

```
for i in 'raghav':
    print(i)
```

Comment: @roganjosh Since OP wants to print the word 6 times as of the latest edit, this won't work.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I know, I edited my comment as I was unclear. It was definitely a case of the XY problem but got 4 answers.

Answer (score 2):

You can slice the [`itertools.cycle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) object using [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice):

```
>>> from itertools import cycle, islice
>>> for i in islice(cycle('raghav'), 6):
    print (i)
...
r
a
g
h
a
v
```

Comment: Crafty. Much cleaner than the `enumerate` and `count` options since we know the termination condition up front.

Comment: According to the update, the last argument to `islice` should actually be `6 * len('raghav')`.